# Python replace elements in array at certain range

Tags: python, arrays, range

I've an array, for example:

```
Array = [100]*100
```

Then I want to do this:

```
Array[0:10] = 1
```

The Array should look like this:

```
Array = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,100,100....,100]
```

But Python says No and gives me

```
Array[0:10] = 1 can only assign an iterable
```

What does it want and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Array[0:10] = [1]*10`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `array[0:10] = [1] * 10`, you just need to make an array of the size of the slice you are replacing.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to turn your list into a numpy array, and numpy will [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) your value to the whole part of the array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([100]*100)

a[0:10] = 1
print(a)

# array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 100, 100, 100,
#        100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
#        ... 
#       ])
```

Comment: Very clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example with list:

```
L = [0 for k in range(100)] # List of 0
L[10:20] = [1 for k in range(10)]

# Output:
L = [0, ..., 0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, ..., 0]
```

You need to give a list as well to replace N values.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer jc1850 solution better but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Quotenbanane That's exactly the same, I just defined the replacing list on the right side differently. You should also have a look at the solution given by Thierry Lathuile, which involves numpy. Try to read about the difference between a list and a numpy array.

Comment: well you made a little extra work with [1 for k in range(10)] didn't you?

Comment: Yeah, Thierry's answer is awesome, i agree. But i do not need numpy right now.

Comment: @Quotenbanane That's just creating a list of 1 of size 10. Exactly the same as `[1] * 10`. However, indeed, it's not as efficient.

Comment: I know it's the same but it is a lot slower. That's why i like the other solution better.

Comment: Good work tho, I'm not trying to say your answer is worth less but my code has an array with a size of 10.000, therefore speed matters.

Comment: @Quotenbanane And I do not say my answer is worth more ^^ `[1] * 10` is more efficient anyway :) If speed matters, you should definitely go towards numpy and its broadcasting which is going to be much faster.

Comment: Really? Numpy is faster? According to my code timer it is the slowest. Or does is it the fastest longterm? (i tried it out on a very small piece of code)

Comment: @Quotenbanane Numpy is faster essentially because it uses an optimized C implementation. Now, depending on what you wrote, it might be identical or slower. But, written in the right way, a code doing the same thing as what you want in numpy will be faster. Example: `X = np.zeros(100000)` and `X[500:1500] = 1` takes about 952 ns ± 20.5 ns. The same thing with the list and the solution `[1]*1000` takes 11.6 µs ± 26.7 ns.

Comment: @Quotenbanane Final point, this is why for applications where speed matters it is interesting to replace for loop computation by numpy array-wide computation. You can speed up a code by 10x, 100x, or 1000x depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

the type of operands in both side should be same in this case

```
Array[0:10]=[1]*10
```

Answer (score 1):

#### lists in python are mutable it's not good to write them in the form [100]*100. You might have problems later when your code gets complicated.

I suggest to write it as:

```
array = [100 for _ in range(100)]
for i in range(10):
    array[i] = 1
print(array)

output: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```